# which element is the minimum value of each sublist

Tags: r

I am trying to find out which element of each of my sub-lists is the minimum for that particular  sub-list.  The current chunk of data I am trying to apply the functionality to is a record of 41 entries. They get grouped by another function  that produces indices for each of the sub-lists or sub-group. Elements `1:8` are in the first sub-group, the following sub-groups are as follow:  `9:17`, `18:23`, `24:33`, `34:41`.  Please note I called the data I am working with "`b1`", and the index created to group b1's element into sub-groups is "`indx`". I am able to find out the minimum value in each sub-group using sapply like this:

```
sapply(indx, function(i) min(b1[i])
```

But, I am stuck at finding which "b1" element is each of these numbers sapply provided above. I know I probably need the function `which()` and `mapply()`, but have not been able to put it together.

Reproducible data:

```
b1 <- sample(1:20,41,T)
starts <- c(1,9,18,24,34)
stops <- c(8,17,23,33,41)
indx <- mapply(seq, from=starts, to=stops)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `b1(i)`? Is `b1` a function?

Comment: b1 is the entire record before the sub-lists are created.  b1[i] is to extract b1 components for the min function.  I apologize for the error, I used () instead of [].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically figured it out yourself.

Try

```
sapply(indx, function(i) which.min(b1[i]))
```

---

### Edit

I'm not sure anymore if that is actually what you want. The answer above should return you the index of the minimum element *within* each subgroup.

In that case you could do the following (one of probably quite a few possible ways):

```
indices <- 1:length(b1)
sapply(indx, function(i) indices[i][which.min(b1[i])])
```